# Complicated string split

Tags: r

I have a data frame where some values for "revenue" are listed in the hundreds, say "300," and others are listed as "1.5k." Obviously this is annoying, so I need to find some way of splitting the "k" and "." characters from those values and only those values. Any thoughts?

Comment: `x <- c('300', '1.5k'); as.numeric(gsub('k', '', x)) * ifelse(grepl('k', x), 1000, 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do this is just with Regex (and `tidyverse` for pipes)

```
 library(tidyverse)

 string <- c("300", "1.5k")

 string %>% ifelse(
        # check if string ends in k (upper/lower case)
        grepl("[kK]$", .), 
        # if string ends in k, remove it and multiply by 1000
        1000 * as.numeric(gsub("[kK]$", "", .)), 
        .) %>% as.numeric() 

 [1]  300 1500
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that remove "k", change to a numeric vector and multiple by 1,000.

```
to_1000 <- function(x){
  
    x %>% 
      str_remove("k") %>% 
      as.numeric() %>% 
    {.*1000}
}


x <- c("3000","1.5k")


tibble(x) %>% 
  mutate(x_num = if_else(str_detect(x,"k"),to_1000(x),as.numeric(x)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  x     x_num
  <chr> <dbl>
1 3000   3000
2 1.5k   1500
```